# Reading excel file in angular with header at row number n

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, typescript, frontend

I want to read an excel file in angular starting from row number *5* (say) as header and read columns with header '*colName1*', '*colName2*', and '*colName3*' (If it is not possible to read with this much specification then take a slice of the data based on the specifications). Is there a simple way to do it? All code that I came across is using multiple embedded scripts to do the job.

Here is the code that I came up with. It reads the selected excel and displays it's JSON in the console. It is not able to handle files where the header is not at 1st row and does not read specified columns.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col-md-8 form-group">    
   <input type="file" class="form-control" (change)="uploadedFile($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xlsx">
</div>
```

**TypeScript**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';  
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  storeData: any;  
  jsonData: any;    
  fileUploaded: File;  
  worksheet: any;  

  uploadedFile(event) {  
    this.fileUploaded = event.target.files[0];  
    this.readExcel();  
  }  

  readExcel() {  
    let readFile = new FileReader();  
    readFile.onload = (e) => {  
      this.storeData = readFile.result;  
      var data = new Uint8Array(this.storeData);  
      var arr = new Array();  
      for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);  
      var bstr = arr.join("");  
      var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });  
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];  
      this.worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];  
      this.jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(this.worksheet, { raw: false });  
      this.jsonData = JSON.stringify(this.jsonData);  
      console.log(this.jsonData)
    }  
    readFile.readAsArrayBuffer(this.fileUploaded);  
  }
}
```

I am looking for behavior similar to that provided by pandas in Python:

```
df = pd.read_excel('fileName.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', header=5)
df = df[['colName1','colName2', 'colName3']].copy()
```

I am new to Angular and still trying to figure my way out of the basics of Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is use awesome lib `xlsx-import` https://github.com/Siemienik/xlsx-import

It works great with TypeScript so will be great for your angular app:

```js
interface Book {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
    Author: string;
}

const importer = new Importer(workbook);
const books: Book[] = importer.GetAllItems<Book>( {
    type: 'list',
    worksheet: 'Favourites',
    columns: [
        {
            index: 1, // column index (1,2,3....n) - started form number 1 (not 0)
            key: 'Id', // output item's field (Book.Id)
            mapper: (v: string) => Number.parseInt(v) // nullable, for transformating values
        },
        {index: 2, key: 'Title'}, // (Book.Title)
        {index: 5, key: 'Author'},  // (Book.Author)
    ],
    rowOffset: 6, //offset header row
});
```